# AutoBahn Websoket Login

Tags: websocket, autobahn

I am trying to use AutoBahn to test a websocket server. The server has a username/password. 
  What is the correct way of sending the username/password for authentication? is it within the json file as shown below (ws://username:password@localhost:8787). This does not seem to work for me.
  Thank you.

```
{
   "options": {"failByDrop": false},
   "outdir": "./reports/servers",

   "servers": [
                {"agent": "TestWebSocket",
                 "url": "ws://username:password@localhost:8787",
                 "options": {"version": 13}}
              ],

   "cases": ["*"],
   "exclude-cases": [],
   "exclude-agent-cases": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Autobahn does not (yet) support HTTP authentication (when run standalone, that is not as a Twisted Web resource).

Comment: What is the best/proper way to do authentication then using Autobahn?

Comment: Please see here https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/wamp/authentication for an example. This is for WAMP. For raw WebSocket, you can have Autobahn running on a subpath served by Twisted, and authenticate via Twisted Web mechanisms.

Comment: how can we add headers in websocket duing handshake with the server?